# Show that $f(a)$ converges after some point

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> There is a row of 1000 integers. There is a second row below, which is constructed as follows. Under each number $a$ of the first row, there is a positive integer $f(a)$ such that $f (a)$ equals the number of occurrences of $a$ in the first row. In the same way, we get the 3rd row from the 2nd row, and so on. Prove that, finally, one of the rows is identical to the next row.

Attempt:

I looked at some cases. Suppose all integers are the same then $f(a_k) = 1000, \forall k$. For the third row then, $f(f(a_k)) = 1000, \forall k$. Similarly, $f(f(....a_k)..) = 1000, \forall k$.

I need to find an invariant. Can someone give me hints?

Comment: Do you mean that eventually two rows will be the same? Or that eventually one row will get mapped into itself?. A hint for the first question: No element in the second row and in any row below that is bigger than $1000$, hence we have only finitely many "possible rows".

Answer (score 3):

Let $a_{n,k}$ be the $k$th entry in the $n$th row. So the rule seems to be that
$$a_{n+1,k}=\bigl|\{\,j:1\le j\le 1000, a_{n,j}=a_{n,k}\,\}\bigr|. $$
Then we have the following

**Claim.** If $n\ge 2$ then $a_{n+1,k}\ge a_{n,k}$.

*Proof.* If $a_{n,k}=r$, then there are exactly $r$ indices $1\le j_1<j_2<\ldots< j_r\le 1000$ with $a_{n-1,j_i}=a_{n-1,k}$. Then immediately $a_{n,j_1}=a_{n,j_2}=\ldots=a_{n,j_r}=r$ so that in row $n$ the value $a_{n,k}$ occurs at least $r$ times, which causes $a_{n+1,k}\ge r$. $_\square$

Since each sequence $a_{2,k},a_{3,k},\ldots$ is a  nondecreasing sequence of integers and bounded from above by $1000$, it must be eventually constant, i.e., there exists an index $N(k)$ such that $a_{n,k}=a_{N(k),k}$ for all $n\ge N(k)$. Let $M=\max\{N(1),\ldots,N(1000)\}$. Then $a_{n,k}=a_{M,k}$ for all $n\ge M$, and $1\le k\le 1000$, as was to be shown.

Comment: That is not how I read the question.  I think it may be more like $$ \left. \begin{array}{cccccccc}
1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3\\
2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4\\
4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4\\
8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8\end{array} \right.$$

Comment: @Henry Alright, upon second reading I agree.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Find an [invariant](https://brilliant.org/wiki/invariant-principle-definition/)

- Show that the number of distinct integers in each row is non-decreasing.
- After that, show that eventually a column must be constant. This follows when $1000 \geq f(a) \geq a $.

Hence, since the number of rows is infinite, and a column is eventually repeating, thus there is a row that is identical to the previous.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still stuck. Suppose not all numbers are the same but some are.But how can I use this?

Comment: @Amad27 That does not matter. Which hint are you stuck at? Can you prove the first hint? Can you prove the second hint?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the first hint. I cant show it though. I tried for 30 minutes but no progress. Suppose there are $k$ same integers and $1000 - k$ different integers in Row 1. Then in row there are are $k$ same and $1000 - k$ distinct integers. Still that doesn't help at all.

Comment: @Amad27For the first hint. If $a_1, s_2$ are the same, then so must $f(a_1), f(a_2)$. This tells us that the number of distinct integers cannot increase. It might decrease, like in Henry's example above.

Comment: So is the sequence non-increasing or non-decreasing?